# Codeigniter URLs: 301 redirects always adding a ? (question mark) or extra directories

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

Within codeignitor .htaccess I'm trying to 301 redirect old/unused urls to a new directory/page - but no matter what I do it adds a question mark as  adirecty...and if I take our the question mark from the .htaccess....it still adds the question mark anyway in the url plus the old path...

I've inlcuded my code below:

```
RewriteBase /

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Actually 301 direct all index.php requests
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

# this gets rid of index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Redirect 301 /old-page /newdir/new-page/?
```

So if I was to enter:

/old-page > it would go to >>> /newdir/new-page/?/

or if I took away the question mark from th e.htaccess it would be...

/newdir/new-page/?/old-page

When all I want it...

/newdir/new-page

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_alias` or `Redirect` directive with `mod_alias` (`RewriteEngine`) rules.

Use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^old-page/?$ /newdir/new-page/? [L,NC,R=301]

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Actually 301 direct all index.php requests
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

# this gets rid of index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```